# VPCGatewayAttachment in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I am working to convert a CloudFormation into Terraform. I am currently unable to find an equivalent resource for `AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment`.

This is the original:

```
  AgentVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    DependsOn: AgentVPC
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: AgentVPC
      InternetGatewayId:
        Ref: InternetGateway
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "agent_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "internet_gateway" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.agent_vpc
  ]
}
```

But what is the terraform equivalent for that `VPCGatewayAttachment`? I can only find VPN attachment, which is not what I want (and which doesn't work).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just solved this. Turns out that `aws_internet_gateway` can just take the VPC directly, like so:

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.agent_vpc.id
}
```

At which point the need for `VPCGatewayAttachment` disappears.